# Change Woocommerce Email Header using custom plugin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to change the WooCommerce email header template with a new one so that i could add conditions in header template to get value from dashboard or database. (To change color of header based on user input from dashboard). Please note that i am using a custom plugin file to do so.
I have followed several tutorials and all i received was bunch of errors.
What i did is, i have a class with following code.

```
public function __construct(){
    add_action('woocommerce_email',array($this,'woocommerce_email'));
}
```

Now I have added code to remove default reset the hook:

```
public function woocommerce_email($mailer){
    remove_action('woocommerce_header',array($mailer,'email_header'));
    add_action('woocommerce_header',array($this,'email_header'));
}
```

Now calling the template:

```
public function email_header() {          
    wc_get_template( 'emails/email-header.php');
}
```

I am not passing anything to the template file. So no parameters are passed to functions. I just wanted to see that my template is being taken.
Also i assume $mailer to be a part of WooCommerce class.

Any help would be appreciated.

Please note that this is a plugin functionality so I am not interested in replacing the WooCommerce email templates.

Comment: I have an answer for your deleted question… If you undelete it I will answer.

Comment: which one is that ?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I have deleted Display Order Notes in WooCommerce 3.3.3. Is it ?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec . undeleted